# how to generate a responsive PDF with Django?

Tags: python, html, django, pdf-generation, weasyprint

how to generate a responsive PDF with Django?.

I want to generate a PDF with Django but i need that is responsive, that is to say, the text of the PDF has that adapted to don't allow space empty.

for example to a agreement this change in the text, then, i need to adapt the to space of paper leaf.

Comment: Take a look at [How to make a PDF responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527598/how-to-make-a-pdf-responsive) and [PDF Accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Accessibility). I think you should do some research and then clarify if it is accessibility features you want or compatibility with Adobe Reader's Reflow feature or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

PDF is not built to be responsive, it is built to display the same no matter where it is viewed.

As @alxs pointed out in a comment, there are a few features that PDF viewing applications have added to simulate PDFs being responsive. Acrobat's *Reflow* feature is the best example of this that I am aware of and even it struggles with most PDFs that users come across in the wild.

One of the components (if not the only one) that matters, is that in order for a PDF to be useful in Acrobat's *Reflow* mode is to make sure that the PDFs you are creating contain structure information, this would be a Tagged PDF. Tagged PDF contains content that has been marked, similar to HTML tags, where text that makes up a paragraph is tagged in the PDF as being a paragraph. A number of PDF tools (creation or viewing) do not interpret the structure of a PDF though.