# Bootstrap responsive Iframe not resizing content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I can't figure out how to resize the content of a pdf inside a responsive iframe?

As you can see from the image below the iframe has resized however the content hasn't.

View

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src='@Url.Action("ShowPDF", "BillPayment", new { sessionId = @Model.SessionId })#zoom=150' width="100%" height="525" id="iFramePdf" #zoom="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

[image]

Please advice?

Comment: You want that to only scroll verticaly? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes more or so but with the content readable.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to make the embedded pdf file create linebreaks, have no margins, etc. I mean, it's not a responsive HTML, it's a pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help you :
[How to make a PDF responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527598/how-to-make-a-pdf-responsive)

Just an idea but you could get two versions for the pdf, or two level zoom depending on you iframe width ?