# responsive pdf viewer using bootstrap and angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, pdf-viewer

I have to showing PDF file to HTML using pdf viewer in angular 4. But it is not coming responsive(mobile and Tab view). I am using Bootstrap 4.
How to get responsive pdf viewer in bootstrap?, please help

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div *ngFor="let Pdfdata of pdf;"> 
        <pdf-viewer [src]="Pdfdata.PDFPath"></pdf-viewer>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527598/how-to-make-a-pdf-responsive

Comment: I want Pdf-viewer responsive. My Pdf file converted to HTML using Pdf-viewer. But it is not getting responsive

Comment: Pdf file is not built responsive and the exact sizes from pdf file are set to HTML. Converting static document to responsive document is hard for human, almost impossible for machine. If you need responsive content of document view area, you should write it manually in html. Alternatively you can try to use zoom and scroll pane instead.

Comment: It is not possible to write manually in HTML